# How to setup a viewModel when the data is coming from a Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, fragment, viewmodel

Hi I am working on an app which shows data sent from a broadcast receiver. Currently I've added some callback methods which updates the UI after the data is received. Now I want to introduce viewModel and databinding. So how do I design the viewModel? Here's how the code is now:

Broadcast Receiver:

```
class BroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver(){

    //code

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?){
        //More Code
        listener.onDataReceive(mydata)
    }
}
```

In My Default Fragment:

```
class FragmentDefault : Fragment(), MyDataListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_fragment, container, false)
        loadEngine()
        return mView;
    }

    override fun onDataReceive(mydata: String) {
        textview.text = value
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the way you have it is good, the to pass the data to VM just use your 
``` override fun onDataReceive(mydata: String) {
        vm.onDataRecieved(mydata)
    }
``` 
And then you will be able to use LiveData/DataBinding